# Serial port buffer value unable to translate and non-stop streaming

Tags: c#, serial-port

Currently, I'm making a simple form to read a weighing device model E-8000C using serial port. In the manual book, it stated the command to request current weight is:

> R CR LF

The write event to reset the screen value to zero also not applicable as nothing happen(screen not reset to 0.00).

And the serial port event received a uncommon byte to translate. And it keep receiving like streaming once I write to the com. Below is the code that use to communicate with the device:-

```
    SerialPort _serialPort;
    public delegate void AppendTextBoxDelegate(string txt);
    public void AppendTextBox(string txt)
    {
        if (rtbEvents.InvokeRequired)
        {
            rtbEvents.Invoke(new AppendTextBoxDelegate(AppendTextBox), new object[] { txt });
        }
        else
        {
            string datatime = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss.ffffff tt");
            rtbEvents.AppendText(datatime + " - " + txt + Environment.NewLine);
        }
    }
    private void ButtonConnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            _serialPort = new SerialPort
            {
                PortName = InputCOM.Text,
                BaudRate = Convert.ToInt32(InputBaudrate.Text),
                Parity = (Parity)Enum.Parse(typeof(Parity), InputParity.Text),
                DataBits = Convert.ToInt32(InputDatabit.Text),
                StopBits = (StopBits)Enum.Parse(typeof(StopBits), InputStopbit.Text)
            };
            try
            {
                _serialPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(SerialPort_DataReceived);
                _serialPort.Open();
                AppendTextBox("Serial port initialize");
                _serialPort.Close();
            }
            catch
            {
                AppendTextBox("Serial port unable to initialize");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            AppendTextBox("Exception ButtonConnect_Click. " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
    private string PrintBytes(byte[] byteArray)
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder("{");
        for (var i = 0; i < byteArray.Length; i++)
        {
            //var b = byteArray[i];
            var b = new BigInteger(byteArray[i]);
            sb.Append(b.ToString("X2"));
            if (i < byteArray.Length - 1)
            {
                sb.Append(" ");
            }
        }
        sb.Append("}");
        return sb.ToString();
    }
    private string Bytes_To_String(byte[] bytes_Input)
    {
        // convert the byte array back to a true string  
        string strTemp = "";
        for (int x = 0; x <= bytes_Input.GetUpperBound(0); x++)
        {
            int number = int.Parse(bytes_Input[x].ToString());
            strTemp += "0x" + number.ToString("X").PadLeft(2, '0') + " ";
        }
        // return the finished string of hex values  
        return strTemp;
    }
    private delegate void InvokeDataReceived();
    private void SerialPort_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (InvokeRequired)
            {
                BeginInvoke(new InvokeDataReceived(() => { SerialPort_DataReceived(sender, e); }));
                return;
            }
            if (!ContinueRead)
                return;
            SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
            int bytes = sp.BytesToRead;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[bytes];
            int nbrDataRead = sp.Read(buffer, 0, bytes);
            if (nbrDataRead == 0)
                return;
            AppendTextBox($"Buffer: {Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer)}");
            AppendTextBox($"Request: {PrintBytes(buffer)}");
            AppendTextBox($"Received Hex: {Bytes_To_String(buffer)}");
            AppendTextBox($"Received Buffer: {BitConverter.ToString(buffer).Replace("-", " ")}");
            AppendTextBox($"Received ASCII: {Encoding.Default.GetString(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)}");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            AppendTextBox($"Exception on SerialPort_DataReceived. Ex-{ex.Message}. Stack Trace-{ex.StackTrace}");
        }
    }
    bool ContinueRead = false;
    private void BtnWeight_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!_serialPort.IsOpen)
            {
                _serialPort.Open();
            }
            byte[] Buffer = new byte[3];
            Buffer[0] = 0x52;
            Buffer[1] = 0x0D;
            Buffer[2] = 0x0A;
            ContinueRead = true;
            _serialPort.Write(Buffer, 0, 3);
            AppendTextBox($"Write: {Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Buffer)}");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            AppendTextBox("Exception BtnWeight_Click. " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
    private void ButtonStopStream_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            ContinueRead = false;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            AppendTextBox("Exception ButtonStopStream_Click. " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

The result:-
[image: Windows form]

The current weight that appear on device is 1.06 with unit 'g'. Is there some mistake on the code that I have right now? Because none of the value is readable.

Yesterday, the result is different where some of the value is readable as per below:-
[image: Result saving to textfile]

Answer (score 0):

I normally use

```
System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(byteArray)
```

in order to translate byte arrays to string. It has always worked for me.